# User entries not reflecting in the database

Tags: php, html, database, forms

I have connected the php code below to my html file to acquire inputs from users. But when an entry is made it doesn't reflect in my database.The user gets redirected to a different page(contact.php) and the feedback he/she gets is page isn't working right now.
[image: feedback when users make entries]

```
 <?php 

$name = $_POST['Name']
$phone = $_POST['Phone']
$email = $_POST['Email']
$message = $_POST['Message']

$conn = new mysqli('localhost','root','','circlecu_resultorientedmarket');
if($conn -> connect_error){
    die('Connection Failed:'.$conn->connect_error );
}else{
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("insert into registration(Name, Phone, Email, Message)
    values(?,?,?,?)");
    $stmt ->bind_param("siss",$name,$phone,$email,$message);
    $stmt -> execute();
    $stmt->close();
    $conn->close();
}
?>
```

Below is the html form.

```
                        <form action="contact.php" class="contact-form">
                            <div class="input-wrapper">
                            <label for="name" class="input-label">Name *</label>

                            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required placeholder="Type Name" class="input-field">
                            </div>

                            <div class="input-wrapper">
                                <label for="phone" class="input-label">Phone</label>
    
                                <input type="tel" name="phone" id="phone"  placeholder="Type Phone Number" class="input-field">
                            </div>

                            <div class="input-wrapper">
                                <label for="email" class="input-label">Email Address *</label>
    
                                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required placeholder="Type Email Address" class="input-field">
                            </div>

                            <div class="input-wrapper">
                                <label for="message" class="input-label">How can we help you? *</label>
    
                                <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Type Description" required class="input-field"></textarea>
                            </div>

                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send message</button>
                        </form>
```

1. How can i make user entries reflect in my database?
   2.How can i make the page refresh after users click on the submit button?

Comment: A phone number should be a string, not an integer.

Answer (score 0):

1. I can see some syntax errors in your code: missing semi columns and undefined variables.
2. Your HTML form is sending the data using GET method but the PHP script is expecting the request in POST method.

Make the following changes

MAKE SURE YOU HAVE database 'circlecu_resultorientedmarket' and table 'registration' already created.

Otherwise create a file and name it create.php and paste the following code. The code will create a database called 'circlecu_resultorientedmarket' and a table called 'registration'.

// create.php

```
<?php 
 // Connecting to the mysql
$conn = new mysqli('localhost','root','');
if($conn -> connect_error){
    die('Connection Failed:'.$conn->connect_error );
}else{

  // Create database
$sql = "CREATE DATABASE circlecu_resultorientedmarket";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
  echo "<p>Database created successfully</p>";
} else {
  echo "<p>Error creating database: $conn->error </p>";
}

}

// Connecting to the database
$conn = new mysqli('localhost','root','','circlecu_resultorientedmarket');
if($conn -> connect_error){
    die('Connection Failed:'.$conn->connect_error );
}else{


// Create table
$sql = "CREATE TABLE registration (
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
Name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
Phone VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
Email VARCHAR(50),
Message VARCHAR(300)
)";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
  echo "<p>Table registration created successfully</p>";
} else {
  echo "<p>Error creating table: $conn->error <p>";
}

$conn->close();

}
```

Inside 'contact.php' replace the existing code with the following code.

```
 <?php 

$name = $_POST['name'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$conn = new mysqli('localhost','root','','circlecu_resultorientedmarket');
if($conn -> connect_error){
    die('Connection Failed:'.$conn->connect_error );
}else{

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("insert into registration (Name, Phone, Email, Message)
    values(?,?,?,?)");

    $stmt ->bind_param("ssss",$name,$phone,$email,$message);
    $stmt -> execute();
    $stmt->close();
    $conn->close();


   echo "<h2>Thank you,  $name </h2>";
   echo '<p style="font-size:20px;">Your account has been created successfully</p>';

}
?>
```

Then inside HTML make sure to add method="POST" to the form.

```
<form action="contact.php" method="POST" class="contact-form">
```

After starting the server go to the  browser and type  "https://circlecuemedia.com/create.php". If nothing goes wrong, this will create the database and the table if they don't already exist.

You can then try to submit the form again.